# Turn off log output when formatting

Tags: prettier

Run:

```
prettier --write .
```

How turn off log output when formatting in prettier?

Comment: use [loglevel](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--loglevel) `silent`  ?

Comment: @Luuk, yes it is!) Please create an answer.

Comment: The answer would be to do some research (like reading the docs), read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Before%20posting%20a%20question%2C%20we%20strongly%20recommend%20that%20you%20spend%20a%20reasonable%20amount%20of%20time%20researching%20the%20problem%20and%20searching%20for%20existing%20questions%20on%20this%20site%20that%20may%20provide%20an%20answer.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
prettier --log-level silent
```

Source: https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--log-level

Comment: Update: --loglevel has been renamed to --log-level: https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--log-level